# Заполнение массива глобальной структуры

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли заполнить массив включенный в глобальную структуру циклом при этом не в теле функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MY_SIZE 150

typedef struct {
  uint32_t Num;
  uint32_t Enable;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b[MY_SIZE];    
} userstruct;

userstruct myStruct = {
  .Num    = 6,
  .Enable = 1,
  .a       = 10,
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < MY_SIZE; i++) {
    .b[i] = i;      
  }
};

int main() {
    printf("%d", myStruct.b[149]);
    return 0;
}
```

Конечно, можно это сделать в main через цикл, но есть ли способ сделать это иначе не в теле функции?
Текущий код выдает ошибку: "error: expected expression before ‘for’"

Comment: Приводите Текст ошибки и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статические переменные компилятор не умеет динамически создавать.

Существую способы мета-программирования в Си используя двойную компиляцию. Вы создаёте программу, которая сама пишет код на Си, а потом компилируем уже всю программу.

makemeta.c :

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# define MY_SIZE 150

int main(){
  FILE * f = fopen("meta.h","w");
  fprintf(f,"// код создан автоматически, для изменения используйте\n");
  fprintf(f,"// gcc makemeta.c -o makemeta && ./makemeta\n");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < MY_SIZE; i++) {
    fprintf(f,"[ %u ] = %u ,\n" , i , i ) ;      
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

main.c :

```
userstruct myStruct = {
  .Num    = 6,
  .Enable = 1,
  .a       = 10,
  .b = {
# include "meta.h"
  }
};
```

компилируем :

```
$ gcc makemeta.c -o makemeta
$ ./makemeta
$ gcc main.c -o main
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать препросессор.
Например, с использованием boost:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define MY_SIZE 150

typedef struct {
  uint32_t Num;
  uint32_t Enable;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b[MY_SIZE];    
} userstruct;

userstruct myStruct = {
  .Num    = 6,
  .Enable = 1,
  .a       = 10,
  .b = {
      #define ELEMENT(z,i,unused_data) i
      BOOST_PP_ENUM( MY_SIZE, ELEMENT , unused_data )
      #undef ELEMENT  
  },
};

int main() {
    printf("%d", myStruct.b[149]);
    return 0;
}
```

Несколько упрощая, работает  это так:
Макрос `BOOST_PP_ENUM` после подстановки в него конкретного числа MY_SIZE, с использованием оператора склейки лексем `##` заменятся на один из макросов `BOOST_PP_ENUM_1, BOOST_PP_ENUM_2, ... , BOOST_PP_ENUM_256`. Каждый из которых, в свою очередь, определен, примерно, так:

```
 #define BOOST_PP_ENUM_1(z, MACRO, DATA) MACRO(z,0,DATA)
 #define BOOST_PP_ENUM_2(z, MACRO, DATA) BOOST_PP_ENUM_1(z, MACRO, DATA), MACRO(z,1,DATA)
 #define BOOST_PP_ENUM_3(z, MACRO, DATA) BOOST_PP_ENUM_2(z, MACRO, DATA), MACRO(z,2,DATA)
...
 #define BOOST_PP_ENUM_256(z, MACRO, DATA) BOOST_PP_ENUM_255(z, MACRO, DATA), MACRO(z,255,DATA)
```

Т.е. для целого N, определенного в качестве переменной препроцессора,
`BOOST_PP_ENUM(N, MACRO, DATA)` после подстановки, превратится в `MACRO(z,0,DATA), MACRO(z,1,DATA), ... , MACRO(z,N-1,DATA)`. Если макрос MACRO определен то он будет подставлен с соответствующими аргументами.

Недостатки и ограничения такого подхода:

- размер N должен быть переменной препроцессора, содержащей число, а не константой и не макросом содержащим выражение.
- заголовочные файлы boost/preprocessor большие, и требуют большого числа итераций подстановки препроцессора, что может заметно замедлить компиляцию, особенно, если злоупотреблять использованием этой библиотеки в заголовочных файлах. Также, рекомендую включать только минимально необходимый набор заголовков и не в коем случае не boost/preprocessor.hpp.
- Максимальное число итераций, для repitition, ограничено макросом BOOST_PP_LIMIT_REPEAT, который (по умолчанию) равен 256. (его можно поднять до 512 или 1024, но с этими ограничениями справляются не все компиляторы, из-за ограничений компилятора по длительности цикла подстановки макросов (так они борются с экспоненциальным ростом текста, на этапе препроцессора).

Другие возможности библиотеки boost/preprocessor/repetition:

- Если потребуется повторить текст без разделителя `,`  то используйте BOOST_PP_REPEAT.
- Если потребуется сделать константу N - зависимой от других констант, то в простых случаях можно использовать boost/preprocessor/arithmetic. Например, `BOOST_PP_ADD(3,4)` будет раскрыто в 7, а не в выражение 3+4. В сложных случаях, я ввожу отдельную переменную задавая ей собственное значение и только проверяю, что значения переменных препроцессора согласованны между собой.

Почти наверняка, существуют аналоги библиотеки boost/preprocessor ориентированные на использование именно в C (не C++), но я их не знаю.

Comment: А объяснить, как это работает (следовательно, стоит ли ставить boost для программирования на С) сможете?

Answer (score 0):

Если циклом, то для таких вещей есть конструктор по умолчанию:

```
#define MY_SIZE 150

struct userstruct
{
  uint32_t Num;
  uint32_t Enable;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b[MY_SIZE];    
  userstruct(); 
};

userstruct::userstruct()
{
    Num    = 6;
    Enable = 1;
    a      = 10;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < MY_SIZE; i++) 
        b[i] = i;      
}

int main() 
{
    userstruct st_obj;
    printf("%d\n", st_obj.b[140]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что этот код будет работать только в С++ компиляторе

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct user {
    int a;
    int b;
    char *c;
} user = {1, 2, "koko"},
  l    = {33, 22, "pituh"};

typedef struct user user_t; 

int main() {
    printf("%d %d %s\n", user.a, user.b, user.c);
    user_t b = {.a = 12, .c = "jojo", .b = -1};
    printf("%d %d %s\n", b.a, b.b, b.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не является ответом, почитайте ещё раз вопрос

Comment: Ага, промахнулся. Не заметил сразу.